# get values(fields) of enum from reflected string representation

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I have a string representation of an enum.

```
string val = "namespace_name.enum_name";
```

I can use this to get type of enum.

```
Type myType = Type.GetType(val);
```

Now I see myType.Name = actual_enum_name and other informations, good.
I have tried to obtain the actual enum values using this information and not successful.

I have tried using Enum.Getvalues, however I got stuck in converting the myType, which is System.Type to EnumType, which is what Enum.Getvalues require(?).

I have tried to actually create an Enum object based on the information obtained and got stuck.

How can I get actual fields (list of members) of that enum from here?

Comment: Did you tried using Enum.TryParse

Comment: When you say you "got stuck converting myType" what are you trying to convert it to?

Comment: is there some error that compiler shows?

Comment: @Coding Gorilla: I have tried to convert to Enum Type from System.Type.

Comment: @HatSoft: No I haven't can you give me an example? I have tried with Enum.Parse(Type.GetType("enumname"), myType.Name) and failed.

Comment: @JP_medevice I don't understand what you're trying to do, why would you want to convert it to `System.Enum`?

Comment: @exacerbatedexpert: values of that enum.

Comment: @JP_medevice the url gives a good example on Enum.TryParse http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/87819/Enum-TryParse-NET-4-0

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That should work as is, no conversion required. `Enum.GetValues()` takes a `Type`. The code below works.

```
namespace enumtest
{
    public enum Mine
    {
        data1,
        data2
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Type myenum = Type.GetType("enumtest.Mine");

            foreach (var curr in Enum.GetValues(myenum))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(curr.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This allows you to construct instances of an enum value like this:

```
namespace enumtest
{
    public enum Mine
    {
        data1,
        data2
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Type myenum = Type.GetType("enumtest.Mine");

            // Let's create an instance now
            var values = Enum.GetValues(myenum);
            var firstValue = values.GetValue(0);
            Mine enumInstance = (Mine)Enum.Parse(myenum, firstValue.ToString());

            Console.WriteLine("I have an instance of the enum! {0}", enumInstance);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Suppose i have an Enum `ContactNumberType` then to get values use

```
string[] names = Enum.GetValues(typeof(ContactNumberType));
```

because `GetValues()` method returns an array